# Moment.js - Array with months, weeks and days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im trying to get an array with months, weeks and days in it based on start/end -date. But I'm stuck right here, can somebody help how I should do to get an array sorted by month --> week number --> days of week.

**My function**

```
const getDays = (year, month) => {
   let date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, 1)
   let result = []

   while (date.getMonth() === month - 1) {
      result.push({
        date: moment(new Date(year, (month - 1), date.getDate())).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        day: moment(new Date(year, (month - 1), date.getDate())).format('dddd')
      })

      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
    }

   return result
}
```

The result I want is this:

```
[
  [10]: [
    {date: 2018-10-01},
    {date: 2018-10-02},
    {date: 2018-10-03}
    etc..
  ],
  [11]: [
    {date: 2018-11-01},
    {date: 2018-11-02},
    {date: 2018-11-03}
    etc..
  ]
]
```

Comment: your question is not clear, try to describe it a bit more.

Comment: post the complete result you want (for 2 months for example)

Comment: Updated the result I want